# An Inconsistency in Numerical Approximation

Tags: arithmetic, approximation, fractions

Consider the expression

$$
10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{1+10^5}.
$$

Using the elementary properties of fractions we can evaluate the expression as

$$
10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{1+10^5} = \frac{10^5 + 10^{10} - 10^{10}}{1+10^5} = \frac{10^5}{1+10^5}\approx 1.
$$

Note that the approximation $10^5+1 \approx 10^5$ is used in the last step. Now suppose we use the same approximation, but apply it before we perform the subtraction. We get

$$
10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{1+10^5} \approx 10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{10^5} = 0.
$$

The same logic works for

$$
10^p - \frac{10^{2p}}{1+10^p}
$$

for arbitrary large $p$, so it cannot be simply an issue with the accuracy of the approximation.

Is there an easy explanation of what's going on here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance might be a starting point

Comment: This is called "catastrophic cancellation"; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance .  The subject of numerical analysis is largely devoted to studying & combating this phenomenon, teaching in general how to calculate according to your first example.

Comment: relative to the numbers involved, the error is still pretty small, $(1-0)/10^5=10^{-5}$

Comment: @Vasya yes, but the difference between $1$ and $0$ leads to considerably different answers if this factor happens to be multiplying another and the approximation is applied improperly!

Comment: The _absolute error_ may be small, although that's already food for debate, but the _relative error_ is infinitely big, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Interestingly, the error compounds quickly;
$$10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{1+10^5} \approx 10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{10^5}
\approx 10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{10^5-1}\approx\ldots
\approx 10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{2}
\approx 10^5 - \frac{10^{10}}{1}
\approx-10^{10}.$$

Comment: Should that $10^{-10}$ be a $10^{10}$?

Comment: @Quelklef Yes. Typo, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply an issue of accuracy of approximation.  Let me write $x = 10^p$.  Then your expression is 
$$ x - \frac{x^2}{1+x}$$

Note that $$\frac{x^2}{1+x} = \frac{x}{1/x + 1} = x (1 - 1/x + O(1/x^2)) = x - 1 + O(1/x)$$
so that
$$ x - \frac{x^2}{1+x} = x - (x - 1 + O(1/x)) = 1 + O(1/x)$$

In your second calculation you only evaluated $x^2/(1+x)$ to within $O(1)$, not $O(1/x)$, so naturally you have an error at the end that is $O(1)$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. I should have been clearer with my use of the word "approximation", which I took to be the magnitude of the error $$e = 1-\frac{10^p}{1+10^{p}}$$ rather than the order to which this approximation effectively takes the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

The first approximation is fine. The second on is not, because, $10^5$ and $\dfrac{10^{10}}{1+10^5}$ are large numbers with approximately the same size. You are saying that since $10\,001$ is close to $10\,000$, then $1$ is close to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no paradox.

When you approximate $$\frac{10^5}{1+10^5}=1-0.000099999000\cdots$$ with $1$, the error is on the order of $10^{-5}$.

But in the second case, the same error is multiplied by $10^5$, so that it is no more negligible.

Comment: I don't recall claiming there was a paradox, only a numerical issue.